# None of Custom Payment Module are visible in the Checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, payment-methods

I'm using magento version 2.2.5. Previously in version 2.1 custom payment methods were visible in checkout. But when deployed in version 2.2.5 none of the custom payment methods are visible. Even payment methods like paypal, stripe , square.

Answer (score 0):

Go through database table core_config_data and check if something like modules_disable_output exist in path column. If yes then remove that line.

Comment: There is no such a field in core_config_data

Comment: may be this helps you. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why custom payment methods are not visible in the checkout page in Magento 2.2.5. Here are some steps you can follow to troubleshoot the issue:

- Check if the payment methods are enabled in the backend. Go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods and ensure that the custom payment methods are enabled and properly configured.
- Check if the payment methods are properly installed in the system. Verify that the payment method modules are properly installed and enabled. You can check this by running the command php bin/magento module:status in the Magento root directory.
- Clear the cache. Clear the cache by running the command php bin/magento cache:clean in the Magento root directory.
- Check for conflicts with other modules. Disable all other third-party modules and check if the custom payment methods are visible in the checkout page. If they are visible, enable the modules one by one to find out which module is causing the conflict.
- Check the checkout page template. If none of the above steps work, check the checkout page template to ensure that it is displaying the payment methods properly. You can check the template files in the following directory: app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/templates/payment.